# Programmatically setup email accounts on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, iphone, email, windows-phone-7

I need to create an application for iOS, Android, Windows and BlackBerry devices.

This application will configure email accounts to these devices.
**Can we configure email accounts programmatically?**

Comment: Is it a custom made email client? or default ones?

Comment: Yes lets say I have a file with all the required information to setup an email account. I am using MS Exchagne, I want to send this configuration file to user on mobile via my app, and then app will configure email account on mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you can't. The iOS SDK doesn't let you manage email, contacts and calendars accounts on the user's behalf.

At most you'll be able to give him instructions on how to do it by creating some kind of animated tutorial with screenshots within your app, but nothing more...

Comment: that's what I felt too. Is there same limitations on Android, windows, BB ?